# Creating text from character code in XSLT

Tags: xslt, escaping, ascii

I am transforming documents from one XML standard to another. One of the requirements is that a numbered list uses alphabetical instead of roman numbering. I can create the unicode from the list position but it seems impossible to insert those into the XML output.

Maybe I am simply not seeing the obvious solution here. In JavaScript I would be using the fromCharCode( ) function but I have not yet found a similar option in XSLT.

I am using XSL 2.0 but could also use 3.0 if needed to make things easier.

I created a simple XML plus XSL to show the problem I need to solve. The actual files are much too big to be sharing here.

Sample XML input document:

```
<doc>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some more text</p>
</doc>
```

Required output:

```
<doc>
    <list>
        <list-item>
            <label>A</label>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </list-item>
        <list-item>
            <label>B</label>
            <p>Some more text</p>
        </list-item>
    </list>
</doc>
```

I have tried this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/doc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <list>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="p"/>
        </list>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:variable name="number" as="xs:integer" select="position()"/>
    <list-item>
        <label>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&amp;#',$number + 65,';')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </label>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </list-item>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have used disable-output-escaping on other generated items before (e.g. to put angular brackets into the XML output), but it seems that the standard character codes are not being handled in the same way. My output from the above XSL shows up like this:

```
doc>
<list>
    <list-item>
        <label>&#66;</label>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </list-item>
    <list-item>
        <label>&#67;</label>
        <p>Some more text</p>
    </list-item>
</list>
</doc>
```

Is there any way to do this elegantly (i.e. without me having to create a huge xsl:choose to call out every possible integer label value and then explicitly creating the alphabetical labels?

Comment: Use `<xsl:number format="A"/>`. --P.S. I believe you mean "arabic", not "roman".

Comment: Yes, although I also have to create roman numbering. :-)

Comment: Equally easy using `<xsl:number format="i"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`codepoints-to-string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-codepoints-to-string) and have it convert the number into the letter.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/doc">
        <xsl:copy>
            <list>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="p"/>
            </list>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <list-item>
            <label>
                <xsl:value-of select="codepoints-to-string(position() + 64)"/>
            </label>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </list-item>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or you could use [`xsl:number`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-number) with `value="position()"` and `format="A"`

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/doc">
        <xsl:copy>
            <list>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="p"/>
            </list>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <list-item>
            <label>
                <xsl:number format="A" value="position()"/>
            </label>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </list-item>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. Those are very useful insights.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution for values up to 26 (='Z') would be

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:variable name="alphabet" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>    
    <xsl:variable name="number" as="xs:integer" select="position()"/>
    <list-item>
        <label><xsl:value-of select="substring($alphabet,$number,1)"/></label>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </list-item>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is as desired.
This could be extended to 26*26 by using a `div` and an `xsl:if`.